# How to add typings support to vs code and the tsc command if the module dont use @types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am using the module "Rhea" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rhea) which has the typings for typescript in their own /typings folder (so /node_modules/rhea/typings) of the module instead of delivering a @types module I can install by NPM.

I include the project like

```
var container = require('rhea');
```

which works fine, but container is any here.

What do I have todo that

1. VS COde will give me typescript intellisense for these Typings
2. the Tsc command will check the typings when executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rhea` just does not have typings for default export.
If you need `container` type, you can just :

```js
import container, { Container } from 'rhea'
```

OR

```js
import type { Container } from 'rhea'
```

Please see all available types [here](https://github.com/amqp/rhea/blob/master/typings/index.d.ts)

As you saw, there are no `default export`, only `exports`.

For instance, if you want to use `Message` type, you can import it:

```js
import { Message } from 'rhea'
```

Comment: When I import it instead of using requiere, will I have Typed Modules then instead of any-modules?

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper I have never used this package and I'm not familiar how it works in case of `rhea`.
Just take a look on your `node_modules` folder

Comment: AFAIK, `import` is just syntactic sugar for `require`, so it should not affect your codebase in other way than it does `require`

Comment: Well, then it doesn't do anything else, so what I need is a solution to get the typings working

Comment: I don't understand. Did you try `import { Container } from 'rhea'` ?
It should work.
You can use `Container` a type